# jQuery Scrollify footer scroll-lock

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have integrated scrollify plugin. Whenever, I click on submit button without data, it gives an error. But that error could not be visible to me. scrollify lock the scrollbar. How can i see that error.

below is the screenshot.

[This is the footer with validation. Validation error is below submit button, could not see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUIEs.png)

[This is i have to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNjw2.png)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $.scrollify({
            section:".panel1",
            scrollSpeed:1100,
            overflowScroll: false,
            scrollbars: true,
            touchScroll:false,
            interstitialSection:"#colophon",
            after:function(i) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: pls put some html to throw light on what you had done

Comment: Hey there. Generally speaking, it's really helpful if you provide some kind of code sample. Otherwise, one can only take a guess at what's happening. It seems like what you want to do is apply specific CSS to the error message, such as margin-top:-20px or top:-20px to shift the message into the view.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to call `$.scrollify.update()` after the form is submitted.

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $.scrollify({
            section:".panel1",
            scrollSpeed:1100,
            overflowScroll: false,
            scrollbars: true,
            touchScroll:false,
            interstitialSection:"#colophon",
            after:function(i) {
            }
        });
    });
});`
In this code where should i write the scrollify.update() after the button click of form.

Comment: Add a submit event to your form and call it in there